# Select data from 3 tables with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 3 tables. Orders, OrderItems and OrderItemServices. Each order can contain multiple OrderItems and each OrderItem can contain multiple OrderItemServices.
I want to get a list of data of all orders from these tables in Linq. I could write a join but how do I make an anonymous data type to in select clasue which can give me Order list in this hierarchy?

If I use navigation properties and then select OrderItemServices in side select clause shown below it would fire individual select query for each OrderItemService which I want to avoid.

```
from order in Orders
select new
{
    ActiveOrders = order,
    ActiveOrderItems =order.OrderItems,
    ActiveServices = order.OrderItems.Select(o => o.OrderItemServices)
}
```

Is it possible to group each order with a structure of multiple items inside it and multiple services inside items?

Comment: So you want to avoid using a join?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a hierarchical dataset as opposed to a "flattened" dataset.

Comment: I do not want to avoid. I do not want to fire individual queries for OrderItems and OrderItemServices as it does in query above.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399398.aspx) to start on LINQ To SQL

To get data from three tables you can get idea from the following simple example

```
var data = (from product in context.Products
           from department in context.Departments
           from category in context.Categories
           where product.DeptId == department.DeptId
           && product.CatId == category.CatId
           select new 
           {
               product.Code,
               product.Name,
               department.Name,
               category.Name
           }).Distinct.ToList();
```

Comment: this example is for a 1: 1 relation. i have a 1 to N relation in the tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your context to use eager loading:

```
var context = new MyDataContext();
var options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Orders>(x => x.OrderItems);
options.LoadWith<OrderItems>(x => x.OrderItemServices);
context.LoadOptions = options;

var query = from order in context.Orders // ... etc
```

Then sub items will be included in initial query result and won't cause additional requests to the database. This will use `JOIN` internally to retrieve all the data in one go. You can check generated SQL using SQL Server Profiler.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/12/02/linq-to-sql-lazy-and-eager-loading-hiccups/